# System stalls when allocating a large block of shared memory while performing a large number of IO operations

Tags: performance, memory, linux-kernel, solid-state-drive, aio

I have a workload that involves background threads performing numerous random 4k reads on an NVME SSD file using AIO. The IOPS is approximately 40k. To bypass the filesystem page cache, I opened the file with `O_DIRECT`.

However, when attempting to allocate a large chunk of shared memory (e.g. allocating 100GB memory on a 1000GB machine with 400GB free memory) using `shm_open` and `ftruncate`, the entire system becomes stuck for a few seconds. I'm not entirely sure why this is happening, but I suspect that the memory system may be doing some cleanup work.

My typical memory usage:

1. Allocate a large chunk of memory (e.g. 100GB) and many small chunks of memory (about 20MB each) in shared memory;
2. Use them for a while;
3. Deallocate them and goto #1 again with another size of memory.

These three steps occur in one process, and there are multiple such processes in the system at the same time, and the timing of their memory allocation is not uniform. Whenever large memory is allocated, the system almost always gets stuck.

I noticed that if I remove the I/O task mentioned above, this phenomenon has been greatly alleviated. This is strange because I have bypassed the filesystem cache.

- Linux kernel version: 5.4.56
- CPU: Intel 8336c
- getconf PAGE_SIZE: 4096
- NO swap memory

Comment: When you allocates big chunks of memory, the OS should use huge-pages. By default, there are a pretty large set of available huge-pages sufficient for reasonable allocations (100 GiB is not). When the OS needs more huge page, AFAIK it needs to find sets of contiguous pages so to provide more huge pages and this is expensive because it has to physically move pages, not just change the mapping (because of the TLB needs a big contiguous chunk to be mapped). Regarding the fragmentation of the pages in memory, this can cause some freeze.

Comment: That being said. This should not happens multiple time unless the memory gets refragmented again between multiple runs. I assume the 1000 GB are physical DRAM memory and not virtual memory mapped to a swap storage device (not so rare on VMs).

Comment: Note that providing the kernel configuration flags and the content of `/proc/meminfo` (before and after the reproduction of the observed effect) should help us understanding what is going on.

Comment: I think part of the story here is that the kernel has to zero the memory before handing it over.  That's going to happen at 8 to 16GB/s, so it could be 6 to 12 seconds for a ~100GB allocation.   You should be able to capture this with `perf`.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thank you for your response, I have added further details to the question, and I will collect the output of /proc/meminfo as soon as possible.

Comment: @MikeAndrews Thank you for your response, my next question is will this zeroing process use multi threads?

Comment: Generally, page zeroing are done during the first-touch but IDK for shared memory. THis is a sequential process. It can be parallelized by using multiple threads (parallel first touch on different pages). This does not perfectly scale but this is not so bad on Linux (parallelism at least help to hide the high latency of a page fault). If it is done at allocation time, then it might lock some kernel data structure possibly shader with the IO operation though it would be a bit surprising. You can try to share the pages after the allocation (+ parallel fill) if possible.

Comment: Anyway, `perf` is indeed the way to go here assuming this is reproducible. More specifically, a call to `perf top` should be enough to catch the culprit (possibly by analysing the assembly code if the function name is not explicit).

Comment: @AmorFati no, it's not multi threaded unless you do it.  You would have to come up with a technique to spread out your allocation over multiple threads.